# CSS translate work incorrect in chrome

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to position a child DIV in the middle of a parent DIV with translateY.
But it just run out of the parent DIV if the child DIV is not position:absolute, or parent DIV without a height property.

HTML

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="img-wrap"></div>'
    <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.parent{
    /*
    height:190px;
    */
    background-color:#ccc;
    padding:20px;

    -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
}
.parent:after{
    clear:both;
    content:"";
    display:block;
}
.img-wrap{
    background-color:blue;
    float:left;
    height:150px;
    width:200px;
}
.child{
    background-color:red;
    height:100px;
    /*
    position:absolute;
    */
    position:relative;
    top:50%;

    -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
    -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

Here are a sample
[Position middle vertically](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/BjJmYo)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how you could do instead (based on your below comments).

> - the content inside child DIV will be push to the right of the img wrap. But it
>     will overlay on top of the img wrap if i use position:absolute
> - if I add a fixed height to the parent. it will position the child correctly, but I cannot have a fixed height, because the height of the
>     img-wrap will not be alsways same.
> - can't use a fixed width on child, as the img-wrap's width will be different based on the image sit inside the div.

Using `display: table` will make it easy to achieve what you want.

```css
.parent{
  background-color:#ccc;
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
}
.img-wrap{
  display: table-cell;
  background-color:blue;
  height:150px;
  width:200px;
}
.img-wrap2{
  display: table-cell;
  background-color:blue;
  height:250px;
  width:100px;
}
.child{
  background-color: red;
  height:100px;
}
.child-wrap{
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="img-wrap"></div>
  <div class="child-wrap">
    <div class="child"></div>
  </div>
</div>
<hr>
<div class="parent">
  <div class="img-wrap2"></div>
  <div class="child-wrap">
    <div class="child"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks @LSSon, reason I use position:relative, because the content inside child DIV will be push to the right of the img wrap. But it will overlay on top of the img wrap if i use position:absolute

Comment: if I add a fixed height to the parent. it will position the child correctly, but I cannot have a fixed height, because the height of the img-wrap will not be alsways same.

Comment: @mok_ku My sample don't use fixed height so it will resize.

Comment: but it use a fixed width, which the img-wrap's width will be different based on the image sit inside the div.

Comment: Should both img-wrap and child be vertically centered?

Comment: ya, both should be vertically centered

Comment: @mok_ku Made a new version in my answer

Answer (score 0):

This behavior is because of the `.child`sibling `.img-wrap`.
when you set position to `relative`it would be affected by it's siblings so the `.img-wrap` will affect the position of `.child`.
for the correct behavior change `position` of `.child`to `absolute`.

Comment: Thanks @Farzad YZ , position:absolute will make the content inside child DIV overlay on top of the img-wrap, which will make it look weird.

Comment: If you want the `img-wrap` to come on top of the `child` just add higher `z-index` to it.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're looking for?

https://jsbin.com/gubefiqohe/edit?css,output

You need to set the `.parent` to `position: relative;` and set the `.child` to `position: absolute`. You'll also need to set `width: 100%;` on your `.child` element, otherwise you won't be  able to see it.